# How to lock an API in APIM in azure to a hosted web application in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway, identity-management

I have been looking at various tutorials demoing how identity management works as well as API management in azure but I am not seeing an answer to my questions. I understand that managed identities can be used to authorize azure resource to resource communication but I am not seeing how this is done for a web application. Say for example I have an angular website being hosted on an nginx server in an AKS cluster. I understand that I could use Identity management to create Identity resources that make it so that the AKS and APIM are authorized to connect with one another but how would I do this for the angular running application? This application is running in the client's browser, so it seems like this identity management mechanism would not work. How does one secure an APIM so only a given web application can interact with it?

Answer (score 0):

You could secure your API in APIM with the client certificate, then when the app access the API, validate the incoming certificate and check certificate properties against desired values using policy expressions.

For more details, see [How to secure APIs using client certificate authentication in API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates-for-clients).

Comment: I see how that would be helpful for machine2machine communication but I don’t see how that would lock a front end website to the API... wouldn’t the certificate be available to the front end and a malicious user could take it and use it for malcious purposes?

Comment: @Dan When you set it, APIM policy will check the issuer, subject, thumbprint of the incoming certificate, if the certificate is just from your app, no one else could access the API, to secure the certificate, you could store it in the [azure keyvault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview), configure the access policy of the keyvault, no one else can access the certificate.

Comment: If the angular app is running in the frontend and is making a call from there, how is the APIM going to get the certificate specifically from that running angular instance without it being available to user? Downoading it from keyvault to the angular app will make the certificate available in the frontend. Because the app is public anybody could take it.

Comment: @Dan If so, try to [Authenticate with managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-authentication-policies#ManagedIdentity).

Comment: I’ve read the docs there for managed identity I don’t see that it solves my problem as it says that it will essentially get a token and make that token available to the consumer. If I give this back to the front end then the front end will have this token since this website is public anybody could then get the token